# Mongoid-tree: Why do I only get a children array on Node.new and not Node.create?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

This works as expected:

```
[1] consum »  node = Node.new(name: "p")
=> #<Node:0x007ff032b941d0> {
         :_id => "51e88c41c7e9680108000001",
        :name => "p",
  :parent_ids => [],
    :repeated => false
}
[2] consum »  node.children
=> []
```

This does not:

```
[3] consum »  node = Node.create(name: "p")
=> #<Node:0x007ff03250a6c0> {
         :_id => "51e88c4dc7e9680108000002",
  :created_at => 2013-07-19 00:46:05 UTC,
        :name => "p",
  :parent_ids => [],
    :repeated => false,
  :updated_at => 2013-07-19 00:46:05 UTC
}
[4] consum »  node.children
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because `Node.new` creates an instance of the node object having an empty array while `Node.create` is the representation of an instance of a new Node actually persisted to the database (presumably skipping over the field with the empty array)